# How to extract a token from form html using regex

Tags: java, jmeter, blazemeter, regex

I would like to know how I use the regex in Jmeter to capture tokens from HTML.
I have created a regex but it's not getting what I required.

My HTML code with the token is :

```
<html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">    fetch("../../cookie", {        method: "POST",        mode: "cors",        cache: "no-cache",        credentials: "include",        headers: {            "Content-Type": "application/json",        },        redirect: "follow",        referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",        body: JSON.stringify({ token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzeXN0ZW1pZCI6Im5pcnZhbmEtZGlyZWN0LW5hLXFhMyIsInBpZCI6IjE2NTgwMzQ5MjE4NjgtMUpyM3hhdHNHNElvQkgxNHBWOXZhNiIsImxhdW5jaGlkIjoiNExSRXBBUFFJMkFPN3ZwbUFwazd1MiIsImlhdCI6MTY1ODAzNDkyMywiZXhwIjoxNjU4MDM0OTgzLCJpc3MiOiJQU0kifQ.DjYRQHoPeax9toiE0aC0l2af4DZbSwLNuySrnytDq-I" }),    }).then((response) => {  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);     document.location.href = "../../../index.html";    }).catch((error) => {    console.log(`error: ${error}`);    });</script></body></html>
```

In need to extract the value in between double quotes of token.

The tried regex is : token: "[^"]*

I won't require token text in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regular expression would be something like:

```
token:\s*"(.+?)"
```

where:

- `\s*` - optional number of whitespaces
- `()` - grouping
- `.` - any character
- `+` - repetition
- `?` - don't be "greedy", stop at the first match

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)